# ASP.NET mvc 2 - How to add a "confirm your e-mail address" field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Let's say I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DisplayName("Email:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [Email(ErrorMessage = "Email is invalid")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

In ASP.NET MVC 2, I'd render the text box and validation like so:

```
<%=Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)%>
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)%>
<%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)%>
```

How do I add a second field to allow the user to confirm their email address using the display name and validation from the model's property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decorate your Class with the following Attribute:

```
    [PropertiesMustMatch("Email", "ConfirmEmail", ErrorMessage = "The Email Address and confirmation Email Address do not match.")]
    public class MyModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Email:")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [Email(ErrorMessage = "Email is invalid")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Confrim Email:")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [Email(ErrorMessage = "Email is invalid")]
        public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: And where does that validation message show up in the view? I'm not using Html.ValidationSummary anywhere on the page...

Comment: Have a look at: ModelState.AddModelError, there you can add error messages, i believe it will look something like this: ModelState.AddModelError("ConfirmEmail", "Does Not Match");